# How to simply track when a Stored Procedure is run

Tags: sql

I saw an article posted by Aaron Bertrand (very active here) about how to add some simple logging tracking. Hoping for a bit of help. Article is here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/#comments

I need help with what code to use to call and populate the logging table info and where to put it in each stored procedure.

I created a table `dbo.ProcedureLog` and a stored procedure `Log_ProcedureCall`.

I just need some guidance on what to enter in my actual procedures. I am not using any error catching. I just need the following:

- Time procedure was called.
- Procedure name

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an INSERT statement to your procedures to write to the ProcedureLog.

Comment: If any of your procedural code issues a ROLLBACK you will want to issue   PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION in your logging procedure and COMMIT your log info within that procedure.

Comment: can you please give me an example of what that INSERT statement may look like?   Stilgar there are no ROLLBACKs. Thanks

Comment: Sure:  `INSERT INTO dbo.ProcedureLog(somecolumns) VALUES (someValues)`.

Comment: ok I created the statement but how do I get it to save in the procedure